# Java Hash table keys. Converting String keys to int keys

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a homework assignment where I have to create a hash table for a dictionary, where the user can input a word as the key and it will search and display the meaning.

However I am not sure how the conversion from a String key to an int key works. This is the code I took from my textbook:

```
 public int hashVal(String key, int tableSize)
{
    int hashKey= 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<key.length();i++)
    {
        temp = 37*temp+(int)key.charAt(i);
    }
    temp%=tableSize;
    if (temp<0)
    {
        temp+=tableSize;
    }
    hashKey=temp;
    return hashKey;
}
```

An explanation or simpler code would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This calculates the hash for your string. The `temp` calculation is unnecessary since `string.hashCode()` will do (unless you need to implement that too). A mod operation reduces the hashCode to a hash index. The integer can overflow to a negative number so that is handled too.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea in hashing of Strings (or any general object) is to use all parts of the input so that we get a fairly randomized as well as distributed value.

So for a string we use all the characters in the string to calculate hash value.
Similarly for an object it is advisable to use all significant fields in the object while calculating hash value.

Java, similarly uses a variation of your textbook code.

Question: Why your textbook uses 37? [Java similarly uses a variation of your textbook code with 31 as constant value]

Answer: Using primes apparently results in better distribution of hash values over the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several redundancies. Your hash calculation - while not necessarily incorrect - is nonstandard as well. I'm not sure if it would produce a good distribution, and I think the answer is no.

I suggest two revisions: use `37 * (int)key.charAt(i) + hash`, and get rid of the temp variable.

This thus becomes:

```
public static int hashVal(String s, int max) {
    int hash = 0;
    for(Char c : s.toCharArray())
        hash = Math.abs((hash + 37*(int)c) % max);
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Change the return type of the method. How do you plan to use a negative hash to represent an array index between 0 -> N ?

Comment: Yes, how is a negative hash index useful at all? And thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: @ShuaibParker Right, my bad. Edited. If you just keep it under absolute values, there shouldn't be a problem.